# problem with setTimeout

Tags: jquery, effect

I try to create an effect. the problem is the duration of the effect. for my effect I want to pass an parameter duration. this will set the interval in which the effect runs. how is jquery doing this on their effects? I tried with setTimeout but this is quite complicated.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: *"...this sucks really..."* is not a useful statement. What is it about `setTimeout` that you have an issue with?

Comment: @T.J.: i don't i should give +1 to your comment or flag it.

Comment: @Rakesh: Flag it for what? Or was that a joke...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two fundamental ways to do UI loops in JavaScript on browsers are `setTimeout` and `setInterval`:

`setTimeout` will call a function after a specified interval in milliseconds. The timing is not necessarily precise, and you can't usually schedule something for within 10ms on browsers. It returns a handle you can use to cancel the callback (if you get to it before it happens) via `clearTimeout`. To do a loop, you set a new timeout when you're done processing the previous one.

`setInterval` will call a function *repeatedly* at the given interval (also in milliseconds, also with a typical 10ms minimum). It returns a handle you can use to stop the repeats via `clearInterval`. You don't have to start a new one each time, the interpreter does the looping for you.

Which you choose depends on both what you're trying to do and personal preference. Note that the intervals in `setInterval` are counted from when the callback was *called*, whereas if you schedule a new `setTimeout` at the end of your callback processing, it'll obviously be scheduled from that point instead. If your processing takes any significant time, the difference can be important (but again, which you want depends entirely on the problem you're solving).

I think of "duration" as how long the effect as a *whole* takes to run, which would lie outside of either of these -- it would be a function of your effect code. Most effects I've seen run in steps (not sure how else you'd do them) and figure out how many steps to take on the basis of what duration you give them and what maximum granularity the author thought was needed. For instance, fading from white to black can take 255 steps if you want it to, but that might be too slow (and we'll leave aside discussions of "easing" where steps are adjusted according to how the human eye and mind perceive them). You might do it in 10 steps with a step every 50ms if you were told to take a total of half a second, but you might do it in 20 steps at the same interval if you had a full second to do it. Etc.

Comment: thanks for reply. 

can you give a short example. what I want to do exactly is to have an effect like typing a text. letter by letter. that it looks like some is typing something. What I want to do is set the interval of time between typing a letter. for example the interval is 1000ms. then every second one more letter is shown on the screen..

Comment: @katamshut: You can do that with either `setTimeout` or `setInterval`. I was updating my answer to clarify that a bit as you were posting your comment. HTH.

Answer (score 1):

the basic rule  `position = Initial_value + (change_in_time * start_time)  / duration`

```
function animate(duration){
  var startTime = new Date().getTime();
  var tmr = setInterval(function() {
      var elapsedTime = new Date().getTime() - startTime;
      if (elapsedTime < duration) {
        var f = elapsedTime / duration;
         // Here " f " is in an important parameter in our animation
      }else {
        clearInterval(tmr);
      }
  }, 1);
}
```

Try the **Demo** : **http://jsbin.com/eruko4**

**Note** : In my Example(**Demo**) I'm considering `Inital value  as '0';`

Answer (score 0):

They appear to be using setInterval: http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/effects.js#L340